# compare array of strings to a button click

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios4

I am trying to learn new stuff by creating quiz app

I have created array of question and answer

but answer are in only "Yes" or "No".

I am able to create question to appear randomly 
but i am struck how to confirm or get if the particluar question appearing on screen have solution yes or no

It is very simple app,
just want to confirm if the selected question real answer is yes or no?

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to do at a lower level? I'm not sure what you are asking? (i.e. I want a function that runs when I press a butt and it will tell me if something is in an array, etc...)

Comment: Instead of making two arrays of strings, why not make a Question object with the property of answer, that way you make only one array of objects, and can compare by checking Question.Answer.

Comment: Sorry for poor description,
My app is a quiz app,i have suppose 10 question with answer to all 10 question.But  with "Yes" or "NO" option.
How can i confirm the reply to the question is correct or wrong.

Also question are appearing randomly,i hope it makes more clear now

Comment: Still CBredlow's suggestion is most valid and that it should be done in OOP

Comment: @Atif or even better, if there is a static list of questions and answers, use Core Data to store your information.

Answer (score 0):

there are several method to do this simple task.

one is make dictionary with keys (Question, Answer) and add to array as

```
NSArray *questions = @[@{@"Question":@"Question 1 Text", @"Answer":@YES},
                       @{@"Question":@"Question 1 Text", @"Answer":@NO}];
```

And Generate a random number and get the question dictionary from array and save the reference of question dictionary for further comparison.

```
NSDictionary *curQuestion = questions[(rand()%questions.count)];
NSString *question = curQuestion[@"Question"];
BOOL answer = [curQuestion[@"Answer"] boolValue];
```

Comment: I would strongly say against this method. Apple has created a technology, [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html), just for this purpose. Use it.

Comment: Hello,i am not pro at coding yet...can u help me more by giving more code to explain better

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Core Data would be huge overkill for a simple list of questions and an answer. A simple plist would be FAR easier.

Comment: @rmaddy easier? Sure. Better? No. A plist is very limited in the data types it can encapsulate, and doesn't hold the core concepts of OOP like CoreData does. The ability to have actual 'objects' created directly from Core Data is one of it's largest advantages.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII I don't wish to start a big debate. I'm just saying for this use case, Core Data is overkill. Plus, the OP said this is a learning exercise. Suggesting Core Data for this very simple case is just going to cause further confusion and add a huge and unnecessary learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of dictionaries (dictionary with two keys "Question" and "Answer"), when a question being answered, you can access the corresponding dictionary from array and then get the answer of that question.

Comment: I don't think that a dictionary is best in this scenario. Unlike javascript, where there is no difference between your 'dictionary' and your 'object', in Objective-C, having strongly typed objects (using something like Core Data) is very powerful.

Comment: To ask4asif...
Can u help me with more code to make it happen